# Integral curves in neighborhood of a minimum point of the potential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Let $X: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be a smooth vector field, and $f: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be its potential (i.e. $X= grad\ f$).

When $f$ has a minimum point $p_{min}$ and all points in some neighborhood $U$ of $p_{min}$ are regular points of $f$, is $p_{min}$ a point of  all integral curves in some neighborhood $V (\subset U)$ of $p_{min}$?
I think this is true, but I don't know how I prove this.

For example, the minimum point of $f(x,y,z) := x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is $(0,0,0)$, and this satisfies above.

Comment: Note the example you gave is not for a real-valued function it is for a vector-valued function!!?? But the statement seems to be true I tried hardly to disprove your claim but I failed. But it is nice to give your trial solving it and in what context you encountered the problem, this may help us

Comment: Thanks for your notation. I fixed it. I'll comment for the context later.

Comment: Once I thought geodesic normal coordinates (in Riemannian geometry) may be useful, but all derivations around $p_{min}$ ($=$ limits of $n$-th derivation of all integral curves in $V$) are vanishing.